# checkbox not working (trying to make a search filter) PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

i'm trying to make a search filter with check boxes. When i display all the data in the table, it shows just fine but when i try to use checkboxes nothing happens. Here is my code.

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$sql="SELECT * FROM websiteusers ";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $searchgender=$_POST['gender'];
    $searchethnicity=$_POST['ethnicity'];

    $sql .= "WHERE gender = '{$searchgender}' ";
    $sql .= " AND ethnicity = '{$searchethnicity}'";

}

$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<form name="form" action="search.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Gender:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female">Female
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Ethnicity:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="black">Black<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="hispanic">Hispanic 

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="search profiles" name="search"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Do you get an error message from `or die(mysql_error())`? Also, you show a query but don't show where you display any results.

Comment: use `$searchgender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender'])` to prevent sql injection. And use `mysqli` ode `PDO` instead of `mysql`.

Comment: @sean it doesnt display any errors or anything. Also, i cant display the rest of the code because this site says it's too much code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- WOW!!! Thanks, now it's responding but not in the correct way. when i check male it doesnt give me any values yet i have 3 males on there. your comment about the button's name is what helped me btw.

Comment: That's because you need to loop through the results using a `while` loop. I'll have to come back later, I have to leave for a few hours. I've posted an answer below, but will modify it when I get back if you haven't solved the loop.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am using a while loop. please see the rest of my code in the answers section

Comment: @babyleans I don't see it. I've updated my answer, reload if you haven't seen it. If that doesn't work, will help when I get back. I really have to leave now.

Comment: @babyleans Reload my answer and see under **Edit**. Read it all over carefully, including comments in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place (rename to) `if (isset($_POST['search'])) {` (see notes that follow) above
`$sql="SELECT * FROM websiteusers ";`.

You also don't have a form element called `submit` but you do have a submit button called `search`

```
<input type="submit" value="search profiles" name="search">
```

So change `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` to `if (isset($_POST['search']))` that's the most likely reason it's not working for you.

Your code's execution is based on that conditional statement.

Having [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on would have signaled `Undefined index submit...`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You also need to loop through the results with a `while` loop.

something like

```
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    echo $results['gender'] . "<br>" $results['ethnicity'] . "<br>";

}
```

---

### Edit

Here is a `mysqli_*` method instead of `mysql_*` that I tested and working. Also included is a ternary operator and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for your search variables.

***Nota:*** The ternary operator will avoid getting an `Undefined index...` warning should one of the checkboxes not be selected.

Changed `search.php` to `action=""` since everything is inside the same page.

***Sidenote:*** You may want to use an `OR` instead of `AND` for this line, but have used `AND` - the `OR` has been commented out below:

```
$sql .= " AND ethnicity = '{$searchethnicity}'";
```

**Code:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$DB_HOST = "localhost"; // replace but do not use mysql_ method.
$DB_NAME = "xxx"; // replace
$DB_USER = "xxx"; // replace
$DB_PASS = "xxx"; // replace

$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM websiteusers ";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


$searchgender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['gender']) : '';

$searchethnicity = isset($_POST['ethnicity']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['ethnicity']) : '';


    $sql .= "WHERE gender = '{$searchgender}' ";

//      $sql .= " OR ethnicity = '{$searchethnicity}'"; // either use this

$sql .= " AND ethnicity = '{$searchethnicity}'"; // or this, not both

}

$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

?>

<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Gender:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female">Female
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Ethnicity:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="black">Black<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="hispanic">Hispanic 

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="search profiles" name="submit"></p>
</form>

<table width="70%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>name</strong></td>
        <td><strong>gender</strong></td>
        <td><strong>ethnicity</strong></td>
    </tr>
<?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ethnicity']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>


</table>
```

---

***Footnotes:***

- In order for `AND` to work properly, one of each checkbox needs to be selected.
- If all four checkboxes are ticked, then it won't work with `AND`. You will need to use `OR` in order for it to work properly or restructure the way you query your DB.

You may even want to try a [`LIKE`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm) clause, using `OR` or `AND`, again depending on what criteria you wish your query to be.

```
$sql .= "WHERE gender LIKE '{$searchgender}' ";
$sql .= " OR ethnicity = '{$searchethnicity}'";
```

There are too many combinations to be included. You will need to try them out, and mixing them.

Comment: hello again, thank you! i tweaked it a bit and the male-female filter now works but the ethnicity filter doesn't. it gives me "index not defined" let me update my code in my previous answer.

Comment: @babyleans You're welcome. Did you use the code exactly as shown under my **Edit**? This `$searchgender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['gender']) : '';

$searchethnicity = isset($_POST['ethnicity']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['ethnicity']) : '';` especially. It's a ternary operator. That shouldn't have given off an `Undefined index` warning. I've tested it with error reporting set.

Comment: Yes i did. the only thing i changed was i added an extra $query line, see the reason in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$sql="SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE 0 OR ";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['gender'])){
        $searchgender_raw= $_POST['gender'];
        foreach ($sg in $searchgender_raw)
            $searchgender.= " '" . $sg . "',";
    }
    $searchgender = rtrim($searchgender, ",");
    if (isset($_POST['ethnicity'])){
        $searchethnicity_raw= $_POST['ethnicity'];
        foreach ($se in $searchethnicity_raw)
            $searchethnicity.= " '" . $se . "',";
    }
    $searchethnicity = rtrim($searchethnicity, ",");


    $sql .= " WHERE gender IN ({$searchgender}) ";
    $sql .= " AND ethnicity IN ({$searchethnicity})";

}
$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Now let me know if you do not understand the code

Comment: Can you please check the logs and tell me what went wrong?

Comment: You will be able to get the error using `echo mysql_error()` after runing the query.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
NEW CODE:
hello, this is my new code and the male-female filter works but the ethnicity gives me "undefined index". You'll also notice i have two query lines. This is because the one inside the first bit of code apparently cant be reached by the code at the bottom. Ok heres my new code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$DB_HOST = "localhost"; 
$DB_NAME = "mysite"; 
$DB_USER = "root"; 
$DB_PASS = "***"; // password edited out

$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}




$sql="SELECT * FROM websiteusers ";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $searchgender = isset($_POST['gender'])  ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['gender']) : '';

    $searchethnicity = isset($_POST['ethnicity'])  ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['gender']) : '';

    $sql .= "WHERE gender = '{$searchgender}'";
    $sql .= " OR ethnicity = '{$searchethnicity}' ";
}

$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


?>

<?php
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
?>

<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Gender:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female">Female
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Ethnicity:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="black">Black<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="hispanic">Hispanic 

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="search profiles" name="submit"></p>
</form>


<table width="70%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>name</strong></td>
        <td><strong>gender</strong></td>
        <td><strong>ethnicity</strong></td>
    </tr>
<?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ethnicity']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Place `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` above `$sql="SELECT * FROM websiteusers ";` instead of under it, as I stated in (now deleted) comments, and in my answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it says query was empty when i place isset above the select.

Comment: I'll be back later. Just getting ready to leave. If you still need help till then, I will.

Comment: should i also move the last curly bracket below the query? ok, help me when you get back.

Comment: I tested your code and was successful. You may not be getting results due to `AND ethnicity` try using `OR ethnicity` and make sure data exists inside all columns.

Comment: All your columns exist in your table `name`, `gender`, `ethnicity`? What **exactly** is the warning message? If it's only `undefined index` then it's a table column issue, not a PHP issue.

Comment: Plus, this `$searchethnicity = isset($_POST['ethnicity'])  ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['gender']) : '';` - it should be `$searchethnicity = isset($_POST['ethnicity'])  ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['ethnicity']) : '';` you didn't copy my answer correctly, that's why you're getting a warning message.

Comment: haha silly me!! Thank you! Now the individual filters work perfectly but when i use them both they dont work correctly. for example male and black gives me all males and one female.

Comment: That's where my added notes in my answer explain that. There are many ways to build the query and that will depend on how you want to filter it.

Comment: oh ok. is there somewhere i can learn about these comprehensively?

Comment: Just Google "php search form mysql" and maybe add on "LIKE" or "WHERE". This is just too broad to go into detail.